# What is the easiest way to create has_many association using activeadmin gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, activeadmin

I just using activeadmin gem:

rails generate active_admin:resource Team

rails generate active_admin:resource Players

app/models

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :players
  attr_accessible :description, :name
end

class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team
  attr_accessible :description, :name
end
```

app/controller/players_controller

```
class PlayersController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @team = Team.find(params[:team_id])
        @player = @team.players.create(params[:player])
    end
end
```

app/admin/

```
  ActiveAdmin.register Team do
  end

  ActiveAdmin.register Player do
  end
```

When I tried to create a new Player using the admin interface, I receive:

> ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in Admin::PlayersController#create

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: team_id
```

I know that I have to do something more, but what? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add team_id to attr_accessible:

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :team
    attr_accessible :description, :name, :team_id
end
```

Comment: Easiest, like I said. Thanks.